# Solving multiple integral with symbolical limits

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a double integral, though I am not sure how I could potentially handle the symbolic limits. 
I have attempted the following code:

```
i2 = (xprime^2*yprime^2)/2
xminp = x - 1/2 (y - yprime);
xmaxp = x + 1/2 (y - yprime);
yminp = 0 ;
ymaxp = y ;
I2 = NIntegrate[i2, {xprime, xminp, xmaxp}, {yprime, yminp, ymaxp}]
```

But this gives the following error:

`NIntegrate: xprime = x +1/2(-y +yprime) is not a valid limit of integration]`

Does anyone know how could I perform this symbolical integration in Mathematica? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try using `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate`  Using `I2 = Integrate[
  Integrate[i2, {xprime, xminp, xmaxp}], {yprime, yminp, ymaxp}]` it gives `(x^2 y^4)/24 + y^6/1440`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks it works, but I was expecting a solution only in terms o $x$ and $y$. I get also `yprime` terms. I have tried to use Expand but still get the yprime factor

Comment: There is a bug in Integrate, please use the form I showed in my comment, i.e. use `Integrate` twice, and not one `Integrate` you can see it works OK when you use `Integrate` twice.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks it works! Should I deleted the question as it seems to be too easy? Happy to accept your answer if you post it below though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html), integrals are defined in the order of outermost to innermost:

> The first variable given corresponds to the outermost integral and is done last.

So you need to reverse the order of your integration variables:

```
i2 = (xprime^2*yprime^2)/2;
xminp = x - 1/2 (y - yprime);
xmaxp = x + 1/2 (y - yprime);
yminp = 0;
ymaxp = y;
I2 = Integrate[i2, {yprime, yminp, ymaxp}, {xprime, xminp, xmaxp}]

(*    (x^2 y^4)/24 + y^6/1440    *)
```

Comment: I thought it was bug and was posting question about it but saw your answer.  I did not know the order makes a difference. This is really strange behavior of integrate. But to be safe, I always do integration twice, instead of having to remember to change the order manually.